# Uniqueness of 1-dimensional heat-equation with dynamic boundary condition

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

My question regards uniqueness of the pair $(u(t, x), v(t))$ which 
satisfy the following one dimensional time dependent heat equation
with a(n) (also time varying) Robin boundary condition at the origin. Assume we are given the initial conditions of $v(0) \geq 0$ and $u(0, x) \geq 0.$
Do these give a unique solution to:
\begin{align*}
&u_t(t, x) = \frac{1}{2}u_{xx}(t, x) + v(t)u_x(t, x), \text{ when } x > 0\\
&u_x(t, 0) = 2v(t)u(t, 0)\\
&\frac{d}{dt}v(t) = \frac{1}{2}u(t, 0).
\end{align*}
Say these equations hold as functions, not just as distributions. Although
if someone can answer the weak-uniqueness that'd also be useful.

PDE's are not my research area, so any references or additional comments
would be greatly appreciated.